# Accessing parent scope working without ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have accessed my parent scope plenty of times via $scope.$parent, however i am trying to integrate the `ui-router` within my project and no long have access to $scope.parent

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hdoXBngnMatk6HKj4fMC?p=preview

Ive created 2 buttons, one with nested view and controller, and one without.. When you click on the button that is not nested:

- 1: `errorBanner` is set to true
- 2: `{{myMessage}}` gets set a value

However, on click of the button that is nested, `{{myMessage}}` no longer updates.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');

    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/index',
            templateUrl: 'view.html'
        })
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.controller('nestedController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setValue = function () {
    $scope.$parent.errorBanner = true;
    $scope.$parent.myMessage = 'hey, it updated!';
  }
});

app.controller('nonNestedController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setValue = function () {
    $scope.$parent.errorBanner = true;
    $scope.$parent.myMessage = 'hey, it updated!';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow [**dot rule**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) while defining `ng-model` to avoid `$parent` annotation. By following dot rule you could get the prototypically inherited scope inside your child controller.

**Markup**

```
  <p>Something should appear below on click: </p>
  <div class="hero-banner-error" data-ng-show="model.errorBanner">
      <p>{{ model.myMessage }}</p>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.model = {};
});

app.controller('nestedController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setValue = function () {
    $scope.model.errorBanner = true;
    $scope.model.myMessage = 'hey, it updated!';
  }
});

app.controller('nonNestedController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setValue = function () {
    $scope.model.errorBanner = true;
    $scope.model.myMessage = 'hey, it updated!';
  }
});
```

Also don't assign a controller from the `view.html` itself which has been loaded from state, your state should be like below, and remove ng-controller from `view.html`

```
$stateProvider
.state('index', {
  url: '/index',
  templateUrl: 'view.html',
  controller: "nestedController"
})
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fVmnC4aDqEUJQdQRMBHm?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for this, would you also recommend the 'as' annotation when inheriting controllers?

Comment: @OamPsy i dont because they are useful on HTML..in the end you need to do `this.$parent` to get the value of parent controller..

Comment: your plunker doesnt represent the this.$parent change.

Comment: the given plunkrbis for dot rule not for `controllerAs`??

Comment: i have marked your answer as the answer, although, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Although Pankajs answer feels like the correct one, i have found another way around it.

By simply removing the declaration of the nestedController from my .html file, and declaring it in app.js instead, i can access the $parent $scope:

**Old:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: 'view.html'
    })
```

**New:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        controller: 'nestedController'
    })
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hdoXBngnMatk6HKj4fMC?p=preview